# How to have two programs communicate using std io?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, process

I have two different programs A and B.
Both the programs take user input from stdin and output to stdout.
How can I have the programs talk to each other?
i.e. i want program A to use B as it's stdout and stdin and program B to take A's output as stdin and give it's own output to A.

I can't seem to figure out how i can do it using Linux pipelines.

I'm using bash. I want a solution which doesn't involve creating another program or modifying any of the existing ones.

Comment: You could do this with a script which successively calls `A` and `B`, using temporary files to store the output of one to reuse as the input to another.  That's batch-input.  But doing it continuously would require some real work.

Comment: Pipelines are for one-way communication. Unix domain sockets are for two-way communication.

Answer (score 1):

`socat` lets you relay I/O from anything to anything else and back, including between two programs:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash -e
var="World"
echo "$var"
echo "a wrote '$var'" >&2
read -r var
echo "a read '$var'" >&2

$ cat b
#!/bin/bash -e
read -r var
echo "b read '$var'" >&2
echo "Hello $var"
echo "b replied" >&2

$ chmod +x a b

$ socat exec:./a exec:./b
b read 'World'
b replied
a wrote 'World'
a read 'Hello World'
```

Note that it is your responsibility to avoid deadlocks by ensuring that both programs flush their buffers appropriately.

If you e.g. replace `exec:./b` with `exec:rev`, you will cause a deadlock because most standard tools will buffer output to pipes by default.

Answer (score 1):

> i want program A to use B as it's stdout and stdin and program B to take A's output as stdin and give it's own output to A.

Create two fifos and run `A | B` in background, but connect input to A from a fifo and output from B to a fifo. Then connect fifos together with cat:

```
fifoAin=$(mktemp -u)
fifoBout=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$fifoAin" "$fifoBout"
A < "$fifoAin" | B > "$fifoBout" &
cat < "$fifoBout" > "$fifoAin"
```

The following, although looks cool, will not(!) work, because `cat` will block on file descriptor:

```
exec 3<> <(A | B)
cat <&3 >&3
```

Example with comments:

```
# output 1
# then read number and if a number is greater then 20
# output the number on stderr and exit
# otherwise add to number 3 and output
A() {
  echo 1
  while read n; do
    if ((n > 20)); then
      echo "Answer: $n" >&2
      break;
    fi
    echo "$((n + 3))"
  done
}


# read a number and output the number multiplied by 2
B() {
  while read n; do
    echo "$((n * 2))"
  done
}

# the code
fifoAin=$(mktemp -u)
fifoBout=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$fifoAin" "$fifoBout"
A < "$fifoAin" | B > "$fifoBout" &
cat < "$fifoBout" > "$fifoAin"
```

Will output on stderr:

```
Answer: 26
```

Comment: You might want an example to your goood (upvoted) answer. I tested it with program A `echo 5; for ((n=0;n<10;n++)); do read -r i; ((j=2*i)); >&2 echo "a: $i*2=$j";  echo "$j"; done` and program B `for ((n=0;n<10;n++)); do read -r i;    ((j=i+1));    >&2 echo "   b: $i + 1 = $j"; echo "$j"; done` .

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth thinking about what you need to achieve and the best way to do that.

You have a problem with the current software. The solution (pseudo code) (A || B) && (B || A) is difficult to achieve properly, even with `bash`. There may well be easier, cleaner solutions. Such as removing dependencies between A and B, or modifying the software so that A depends on B, or vice versa.

For example if B depended solely on the output of A, all that is needed is connect A and B with a pipe, and the data streams from A to B:

```
A || B
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want it unidirectional.
A and B are just individual programs and I prefer not to modify them to have them communicate with one another. Think of them as two chatbots if that makes my question clear. I don't really want to create temp files but I guess I'll have to make a script and store the outputs in the file(s) as suggested by a comment on the question. I was hoping for some cmd trick or a program i haven't heard of that does the job. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: What you want to do can be done with lower level programming, but not easily  in bash.